# Converting CSV to Json in Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have an excel spreadsheet(saved as a csv file) of four columns. The first and third columns contain words, the second and fourth columns contain frequency. So it looks something like this:

```
word1, freq1, word2, freq2
word3, freq3, word4, freq4
```

...and so on

I have the following code that converts the csv to the json file.

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('sample.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('sample.json', 'w')


fieldnames = ("feature","r", "feature","r")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )
jsonfile.write(out)
```

Really simple         stuff. 
This, however, returns a json file that looks like this

```
[{"r" : freq2 "feature" : "word2"} {"r" : freq1 "feature" : "word1"}{"r" : freq4 "feature" : "word4"}{"r" : freq3 "feature" : "word3"}]
```

I'm trying to figure out a way so that the returning json file will look like this

```
[{"word1" : freq1}{"word2" :freq2}{"word3" :freq3}{"word4" :freq4}]
```

In another words, I want to make column one of my spread sheet the key of column 2, and column 3 the key for column 4.

Comment: added some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately python's DictReader isn't well suited for your use case, but a little `zip` magic should do the trick.

```
import csv, json

csvfile = open('sample.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('sample.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("word1","freq1", "word2","freq2")
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, fieldnames)

out = json.dumps( [ dict(zip(row[::2], row[1::2])) for row in reader ] )
jsonfile.write(out)
```

`dict(zip(row[::2], row[1::2]))` creates a dictionary that maps from the odd columns to the corresponding even columns of a row.

Comment: when I run it, it tells me line "out = json.dumps( [ dict(zip(row[::2], row[1::2])) for row in reader ] )" has "TypeError: unhashable type"

Comment: Unhashable type list?

Comment: Could you give me a sample csv line that reproduces the error?  With `a,0,b,1` as my input in `sample.csv`, I get an output of `[{"a": "0", "b": "1"}]` in `sample.json`

Comment: the csv file is stored in excel. So it looks something like this

Comment: I'm still getting valid outputs.  See if you can open the csv with something other than excel (notepad/sublime/etc.) and post the raw file data.  I'm pretty sure it's a formatting error, and that's hard to track down without seeing the exact input.

Comment: (I'm sorry I'm terrible at editing comments)
at work(FIRST COLUMN)-0.214489368(SECOND):D(THIRD)0.309759441(FOURTH)
back to work(FIRST)-0.209717058(SECOND)XD(THIRD)0.299062275(FOURTH)

you have words in the first column, their corresponding frequency in the second. then other words in the 3rd column, and their corresponding frequency in the fourth column

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more wordy but can you give a try with this?

```
import csv, json

def dump_to_json():                     
    csv_result = []
    with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:                
        for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'):
            csv_result.append({'word1': row['word1'], 'freq1': row['freq1'], 
                               'word2': row['word2'], 'freq2': row['freq2']})        

    json_feed = [{c['word1']: c['freq1'], c['word2']: c['freq2']} for c in csv_result]

    with open('sample.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(json_feed, outfile)       

dump_to_json()
```

Comment: I did. it didn't, however, return any file :/ I got no error either.

Comment: did you call the method dump_to_json() in your python code?

Comment: no. I thought json.dump(json_feed, outfile) would suffice. If I were to add that line, where exactly in the code?

Comment: I have edited the answer, including import and calling the function.

Comment: mhm I'm getting "KeyError: word1". I should probably specify this (edited my post already). The csv files contains 4 columns, each column having 30+ entries. I want to map the data in second column to first column and fourth column to 3rd column, using 1st and 3rd column as keys.

Comment: You need to replace "word1" with exactly the same as your header for column1, and do the same for the rest, word2: column3 header, freq1: column2 header and freq2: column4 header, they need to be exactly match. The error was suggesting that you call it differently in your sample.csv.

Comment: thanks! now the code works and I got a very nice json file in return. However, it gets back something like {"word" : "freq"} I was looking for something like {"word" : freq} so I can access freq through the key word.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had data like this:

```
feature, r, feature, r
word1, freq1, word2, freq2
word3, freq3, word4, freq4
```

Here is an illustrated solution if I am allowed to use my own library:

```
>>> import pyexcel
>>> r=pyexcel.SeriesReader("sample.csv")
>>> r[0]
['word1', ' freq1', ' word2', ' freq2']
>>> r[1]
['word3', ' freq3', ' word4', ' freq4']
>>> r.series()
['feature', ' r', ' feature', ' r']
>>> r.column_at(0)
['word1', 'word3']
>>> r.column_at(1)
[' freq1', ' freq3']
>>> r.column_at(2)
[' word2', ' word4']
>>> r.column_at(3)
[' freq2', ' freq4']
>>> a=zip(r.column_at(0),r.column_at(1))
>>> b=zip(r.column_at(2),r.column_at(3))
>>> a+b
[('word1', ' freq1'), ('word3', ' freq3'), (' word2', ' freq2'), (' word4', ' freq4')]
>>> j=open('sample.json', 'w')
>>> import json
>>> j.write(json.dumps(a+b))
>>> j.close()
>>> exit()
```

And here is the result:

```
[["word1", " freq1"], ["word3", " freq3"], [" word2", " freq2"], [" word4", " freq4"]]
```

As you can see, there is space left in the quotes. So what you can do is to use a SheetFormatter:

```
>>> import pyexcel
>>> r=pyexcel.SeriesReader("sample.csv")
>>> def clean(value, type):
...     return value.strip()
...
>>> r.add_formatter(pyexcel.formatters.SheetFormatter(str, clean))
>>> r.column_at(0)
['word1', 'word3']
>>> r.column_at(1)
['freq1', 'freq3']
>>> r.column_at(2)
['word2', 'word4']
>>> r.column_at(3)
['freq2', 'freq4']
```

More documentation is [on pyhosted](http://pythonhosted.org//pyexcel/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://github.com/samarjeet27/CSV-Mapper/

```
import csvmapper

# create map file
mapper = csvmapper.DictMapper([
     [ 
          {'name':'word1' },
          {'name':'word2'},
          {'name':'word3'},
          {'name':'word4'},
     ]
])
# parser instance
parser = csvmapper.CSVParser('sample.csv', mapper)
converter = csvmapper.JSONConverter(parser)
# conver to json
print converter.doConvert(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without imports to **Convert CSV to JSON in PYTHON**.

I'm sure the json and csv libraries work well, but I ended up doing it without them. So maybe this could be handy for someone else.

In short: *This extracts the data from the CSV and builds JSON string.*

Clumsy, but works.

```
#set up paths and vars
csvfile = open('input.csv','r')
jsonfile = open('output.json', 'w')
arr=[]
headers = []

# Read in the headers/first row
for header in csvfile.readline().split(','):
    headers.append(header)

# Extract the information into the "xx" : "yy" format.
for line in csvfile.readlines():  
  lineStr = ''
  for i,item in enumerate(line.split(',')):
    if i < 28:  #I skip the last two columns for my application
        lineStr+='"'+headers[i] +'" : "' + item + '",\n'
  arr.append(lineStr)

csvfile.close()

#convert the array into a JSON string:
jsn = '{\n "entries":['
jsnEnd = ']\n}'
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    if i == len(arr)-2:
        jsn+="{"+str(arr[i])[:-2]+"}\n" #Get rid of the last comma if last entry
    else:
        jsn+="{"+str(arr[i])[:-2]+"},\n" #Get rid of the last comma
jsn+=jsnEnd

#write to file
jsonfile.write(jsn)
jsonfile.close()
print "Done."
```

Adding this more as reference for someone else who may need a script like this in a jiffy.